# problem when trying to pass parameters to a react component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

how are you? I'm making a page with react and node using axios and typescript, but I'm having the following problem: when I'm going to pass a list to a component, the variable where I pass the list is dashed red, and when I run the program , the screen goes white and says that it is not possible to map the list, could someone help me?
This is my code:

```
import { ChangeEvent, useEffect, useState } from "react"

import { Button } from "../elements/Button/Button"
import { ContainerStyles } from "../elements/ContainerStyles/ContainerStyles"
import { GlobalStyles } from "../elements/GlobalStyles/GlobalStyles"
import { Input } from "../elements/Input/Input"
import { Elements } from "../elements/Elements/Elements"

import axios from "axios";

export const Home = () => {


    type personType = {
        name: string,
        age: number,
        profession: string
    }

    const [InputName, setName] = useState<string>('');
    const [InputAge, setInputAge] = useState<string>('');
    const [Inputprofession, setInputProfession] = useState<string>('');
    const [personNameToSearch, setPersonNameToSearch] = useState<string>('');

    const [person, setPerson] = useState<Array<personType>>([]);


    const getName = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setName(e.target.value)
    }

    const getAge = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInputAge(e.target.value)

    }

    const getProfession = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setInputProfession(e.target.value)
    }

    const AddPerson = () => { // essa função está sendo ativada, mas está caindo no catch
        axios.post('http://localhost:3333/person/', {
            name: InputName,
            idade: InputAge,
            profissao: Inputprofession
        }).then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        }).catch((response) => { 
            const message = response.message;
            if (message == 'Request failed with status code 500') {
                console.log('Ha informações faltando ou uma informação foi dada de forma incorreta')
            }
            
        }); 
    }

    const GetPersonsInfo = async () => {
        

        axios.get(`http://localhost:3333/person/${personNameToSearch}`, {}).then(
            function (response) {
                const name = response.data.name
                const idade = response.data.idade
                const profissao = response.data.profissao

                setPerson([...person, {
                    name: name,
                    age: idade,
                    profession: profissao
                }])

                
            }  
        );
        
    }

    const getPersonName = (e:ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        setPersonNameToSearch(e.target.value)
    } 

    return(
        <>
            <GlobalStyles/>
            <ContainerStyles>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getName(e)} placeholder={"Nome:"}/>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getAge(e)} placeholder={"Idade:"}/>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getProfession(e)} placeholder={"Profissão:"}/>
                <Button onClick={() => AddPerson()}>Adicionar usuário</Button>
            </ContainerStyles>
            <ContainerStyles>
                <Input onChange={(e) => getPersonName(e)} placeholder={"Nome"}/>
                <Button onClick={() =>  GetPersonsInfo()}>Mostrar Usuários</Button>
                <Elements persons={person}/> 
            </ContainerStyles>
        </>
    )
}
```

```
type personType = {
    name: string,
    age: number,
    profession: string

}
export const Elements = ( persons:Array<personType> ) => {

     return ( 
        <>
            {persons.map((person: personType) => <h1>{person.name}</h1>)}; 
        </>   
    );
};
```

Comment: You've called your props object persons. Rename it to props to avoid this confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
export const Elements = ( persons:Array<personType> ) => {
```

to:

```
type ElementsProps = {persons:Array<personType> }
export const Elements = ( {persons}: ElementsProps ) => { //...
```